# how do you write a simple linux script that performs a secure copy of a hand full of files and enter username and password one time?

Tags: shell, scp

I have about 10 file on my local file system that need to be periodically copied to another server at specific locations.

Normally I would do something like:

```
scp myfile1.txt username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/path/on/server/for/myfile1.txt
<enter password>


scp randommyfile2.txt username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:different/path/on/server/for/randommyfile2.txt
<enter password>


scp anotherrandmyfile13.txt username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:another/different/path/on/remote/server/for/anotherrandmyfile13.txt
<enter password>


scp myfile4.txt username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/path/on/server/for/myfile4.txt
<enter password>
```

I have to do this for all 10 files.  I was wondering if I could possibly write a shell script that remembers my username and password so that I don't have to enter the password all the time?

I would also appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction in using ssh keypairs.

Thanks.

Comment: best thing is to use public and private key mechanism that would eliminate the password prompt completely.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using ssh keypairs?

If the destination paths are the same, then

```
scp myfile{1..10}.txt username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/path/on/server/for/
```

I could devise an expect solution so you only have to enter the password once, but that's a far from optimal answer.

Comment: Hi Glenn - The files do not have similar names and they do not go to the same place on the remote server.